# Install i486 .package onto x64 CentOS

Tags: centos, 64-bit, packages, i386

I am trying to install a ".package" file with Autopackage onto my x64 CentOS server and i receive the below statement.

-sh-3.2$ bash armagetronad-dedicated-0.2.8.3.1.i486-generic-linux-gnu.package
Sorry, Autopackage only supports x86 32-bit systems, or 64-bit systems with compatibility libraries installed. Please install the compatibility libraries and rerun install.

However i cannot find any documentation on what 32-Bit libraries are required or even where to start...

Any ideas or suggestions would be appreciated greatly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that autopackage isn't native to CentOS, or any other distribution that I'm aware of. You'll minimum need the i386 versions of glibc, et all. I didn't find how to get the full list of dependancies for autopackage. And I'm not even sure you have autopackage on your system.

If you have experience building from source, I would suggest you take this as an opportunity to learn RPM. It's fairly simple and straightforward to take an existing RPM, and update it. In this case you would grab the source RPM from http://dag.wieers.com/rpm/packages/armagetron/ and update it with the source file from http://sourceforge.net/projects/armagetronad/files/

You still need any dependencies for armegatron to build. But it's more likely to work, and you can give the RPM  back to the group so that other folks don't have to jump through the same hoops. If you need help, send me a message. I'm happy to help, I've maintained multiple smallish repos for Fedora / CentOS / YellowDog

Comment: Thanks Richard, i ended up finding this link - http://www.pcgooroo.com/download/armagetron/doc/compile.html
It explains how to compile the server without compiling the game part witch requires a whoel bunch of other 3D libraries etc.